# Convert Protobuf to Database schema

Tags: c++, database, schema, protocol-buffers

I'd love to be able to seamlessly send and receive Protobufs from my C++ applications to a Database and back. I'd be happy to create some kind of adapter on the client side, or to leverage an existing plugin on the Database side.

Has anyone encountered something that does this?

EDIT: As for the flavor of database, I'm open to all options, but had assumed a traditional relational database (PostgreSQL, MySQL, etc). If this is the project that forces me to try one of the fancy modern DB technologies, then so be it

Comment: What kind of database are we talking about here?

Comment: It sounds like you want an Object-Relational Mapper (aka ORM) that uses protobuf.  Software and library recommendations are off topic for SO, but googling "protobuf orm" I found traces of such a thing, but only a README; no actual code.

Comment: You should also keep in mind that protobuf is designed to be an stable and efficient storage format. Simply storing the serialized protobufs as-is is often preferable.

Comment: Near duplicate (but for Java), some of which may be useful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45659153/persisting-protobuf-messages-to-database

Comment: @MilesBudnek: If you add a language (e.g., `C++ protobuf orm` or `golang protobuf orm`) it'll lead you to source code.